# Linear Programming in GEKKO Python

Tags: python, gekko

Currently solving a LP problem by GEKKO Library in python. The problem has like 8,000 variables. it runs fine with 462 variables if I increase the number of variables. The program shows an error "Exception:  @error: Model Expression  *** Error in syntax of function string: Invalid element: ,>=0"

Any comment will be helpful.

```py
#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO() 
#Set global options
m.options.solver = 3
m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

#define parameter
Num_Cell= 463
H2 = m.Array(m.Var,Num_Cell,value = 0)
Demand = m.Const(value=20000000) 
D = np.zeros(Num_Cell)
F = Hardwood_Sawlog.SumOfTotal

for i in range(Num_Cell):
    H2[i].lower = 0
    H2[i].upper = F[i]
    D[i] = i

m.Equation(m.sum(H2[0:Num_Cell])==Demand)
m.Obj(np.dot(D,H2))
m.solve(disp=False,debug=True)

print('') 
print(H2)
```

Comment: where is this error found on which line of your program? Please provide the stacktrace..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the symbolic form of `m.Obj(np.dot(D,H2))` exceeds the maximum length of 15,000 characters with the larger problem. Here is a version of your problem that produces an error:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO() 
m.options.solver = 3
m.options.IMODE = 3
Num_Cell= 1000
H2 = m.Array(m.Var,Num_Cell,value = 0)
Demand = m.Const(value=20000000) 
D = np.zeros(Num_Cell)
for i in range(Num_Cell):
    H2[i].lower = 0
    H2[i].upper = 100
    D[i] = i
m.Equation(m.sum(H2[0:Num_Cell])==Demand)
m.Obj(np.dot(D,H2))
m.solve(disp=False,debug=True)
print('') 
print(H2)
```

Here is an alternative version that overcomes the problem with `np.dot()` constructing the long (>15,000 character) symbolic expression.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO() 
m.options.solver = 1
m.options.IMODE = 3
Num_Cell= 1000
H2 = m.Array(m.Var,Num_Cell,value = 0)
Demand = m.Const(value=20000000) 
D = np.zeros(Num_Cell)
for i in range(Num_Cell):
    H2[i].lower = 0
    H2[i].upper = 1e10
    D[i] = i
m.Equation(m.sum(H2[0:Num_Cell])==Demand)
m.Minimize(m.sum([D[i]*H2[i] for i in range(Num_Cell)]))
m.solve(disp=True)
print('') 
print(H2)
```

There are linear programming model building functions in `gekko` that help with constructing large-scale LP problems with sparse matrices or large dense matrices:

[image: linear programming]

An even more efficient way is to use the [built-in model building functions](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming).

Comment: Thanks Dr. John. Gekko makes the world a better place Congrats.